# I baked a normal map on this mesh, but now it reflects light in a weird way. What can i do to fix this?

Tags: modeling, texturing, normal-map

[image]

I baked a normal map on this mesh, but now it reflects light in a weird way. the upper part turns dark!

[image]
Normal map

[image]
Wire frame

[image]
And nodes.

My intintions are to have the light bounce off the plain as if it were flat, like this ...[image]

Comment: Can you show wires/the normal map/nodes etc and explain how you expect it to display? At the moment there isn't enough info.

Comment: Please use your OS' screenshot functionality (e.g. the 'print screen' key)

Comment: Photos of your monitor are very hard to read and not helpful at all in diagnosing shading or graphic issues, please use the OS screenshot feature

Comment: There is no node to get rid of the reflection of the light on the monitor... Please use screen captures and not photos from your phone. Press ctrl+F3 to save a screen shot from blender.

Comment: @Sazerac blender has its own [built-in screenshot](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info/screen_capture.html).

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this would fix it but you should have the "normal map" node between the image texture and bsdf diffuse nodes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use a "Normal map" node before you plug your texture into the normal node of the diffuse shader. 
Shift+A -> Vector -> Normal map. [image]